# How to check or debug AngularJS controller if it working or not?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to check controller is my controller working or not I try to use alert function to test my controller when I create a controller but seem like nothing happened.

**JS**

```
routerApp.controller('myCtrl', ["$scope", "$http", 
"$timeout", function($scope, $http, $timeout){
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'image.json'
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
        $scope.images = response.data.items;
        console.log(response.data.items);

    $timeout(function(){
        $("#lightSlider").lightSlider({
            item:1,
            auto: true,
            loop:true,
            speed:1000,
            pause:3000,
        });
    },0);
    }, function errorCallback(response){
        alert("Something went wrong!");
    });
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="banner">
    <ul id="lightSlider">
        <li ng-repeat="image in images">
            <img ng-src="{{image.img}}"  />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Where did you place `ng-app` and `ng-controller` ?

Comment: I'm missing add controller after declaring State and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are missing `ng-app` and `ng-controller`,
have a look to following code snippet, this is working fine

just added `ng-app` and `ng-controller`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="routerApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div class="banner">
    <ul id="lightSlider">
        <li ng-repeat="image in images">
            <img ng-src="{{image.img}}"  />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('routerApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {


/**
* add your code here
*/
    alert('Debugger');
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```